# use of we and us

Tags: grammar

"I don’t know why us people are so impressed by such groups."

---

Should there be 'us' or 'we' in the sentence mentioned? I feel it has to be 'we' because of the state verb 'are' that follows.

Answer (score 1):

"Us" is not a pronoun in your example. It's a personal determinative functioning as a determiner. So it has nothing to do with the function of subject.

There's no semantic or syntactic difference between "we" and "us" in your example:

"I don’t know why us/we people are so impressed by such groups"—correct

The difference is that of style. The accusative "us" is very informal and colloquial, and is used in many dialectal varieties.

Comment: +1 but I would say that "we" is the norm.